# Reading IIS log file in Log parser

Tags: iis, logparser

Just started to use LogParser. Already existing system is using log parser to read the IIS file and update the db to calculate hits, etc..

I am trying to understand the flow and need to extract two more new fields from IIS log and update the db.

In my local desktop i do have sample log file and log parser. And i tried this query LogParser.exe “Select  top 10 * from c:\LogParser*.log”  in Log parser and got Error: detected extra argument "top" after query. Why i couldnt read the log file which is existing in my local?

And also i got batch file which is in the production. i changed the path to access my desktop files and scheduled the windows task. It is also not working. The code as,
logparser file:Extract.sql?inputfile=c:\LogParser*.log -o:SQL -database:dbname server:test1 -username:username -password:password -createtable:OFF -maxStrFieldLen:2048 -clearTable:OFF

I just need to simulate the existing system to update the database and need to add more fields.
Please help me to go further. i really got stuck.

Comment: The error you receive seems to indicate that you are using funny or smart quotes around your query. Try to type again the entire command (do NOT copy and paste it) and see if it works. That query is a perfectly legal query. Regarding your second example, what do you mean with "It is also not working"? What errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if this would solve your problem, you can try your hands at LogParser Studio - that gives an IDE to the traditional Log Parser.

Definitely easier to rectify your common mistakes, and get help/documentation at your disposal. You can get more info and download it from [here](http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2012/03/07/introducing-log-parser-studio.aspx).

Hope it helps!